# Dynamic TableView columns from a result set (kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

To set the preface: I am a programmer with very limited experience in programming other than COBOL like languages which means I am very new to JVM based programming languages. But I been using python for personal use and am not completely new to modern age programming concepts. Benefit of new bee is expected and please don't shoot down the post.

I am looking to write a query tool. When a query is executed, the data is presented to the user in a table view. So as you can imagine the columns list going to be as dynamic as it can get. Closest I found about dynamic table view creation is here
[Dynamic table columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46734946/dynamic-table-columns)

To write an MVC based query tool, how should the model be created? So that when the data in the table view is updated, it can be updated back to the database and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that when you say 'dynamic table columns' you just mean table columns in which you edit data in the columns and it gets relayed back to the View Model. If you look at the [guide in this page](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part1/5_Data_Controls.html) and go to the section *Using "Property" properties*. It talks about how you can make columns editable. In terms of handling data, [this section](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part1/11_Editing_Models_and_Validation.html) talks all about the basic structure of MVVM. In your case, your database data would be represented by a class representation that writes and reads based into class members. That implementation is up to you however.